# Ajuda com formulário HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax

Desculpem o título do post, é que não estou pensando em algo pra especificar o que estou querendo (fiquem à vontade pra editar). É o seguinte:

Tenho um formulário em html e um botão:

```
<form id="formflor" method="post">

  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" name="codigo" placeholder="código de barras">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Rosa">
  <textarea class="form-control" id="informacoes" name="informacoes" rows="3" placeholder="descreva aqui..."></textarea>
  <input type="file" id="imagem" name="imagem">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editaFlor(1, 'jasmim');">Enviar dados</button>
</form>
```

que ao ser clicado chama uma função `jquery`:

```
function editaFlor(id, descricao){
  if (confirm("Confirma a alteração de " + descricao + "?"))
  {
    var myForm = document.getElementById('formflor');
    var form = new FormData(myForm);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "functions/editarFlor.php",
      data: form,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'ok'){
          alert(descricao + ' editado com sucesso!');
          listaFlor();
        }
        else{
          alert(data);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Esse `form` funciona normalmente, sendo que eu preciso do seguinte: incluir o parâmetro `id` no formulário `form` e enviá-lo junto com os dados do formulário.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Já tentou `form.append('id', document.getElementById('inputID').value);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar o seu `id` ao `FormData`

```
function editaFlor(id, descricao){
  if (confirm("Confirma a alteração de " + descricao + "?"))
  {
    var myForm = document.getElementById('formflor');
    var form = new FormData(myForm);
    form.append('id', id);
    //...resto do código
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar um outro input no seu formulário com o ID e esconder esse campo. algo como

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
```

No value você joga o ID que vc precisa.

Comment: infelizmente, não posso alterar o formulário, tem que ser no botão, pois terei diversos botões para cada item

Comment: Onde essa informação de ID está? Você renderiza a página com ela ou recupera com javascript?

Comment: Você pode, então, passar o id na querystring `url: "functions/editarFlor.php?id=<seu_id>"`.

Comment: A página é criada com um script PHP que já gera os buttons com is respectivos id

Comment: O @LeandroAngelo deu uma possível solução, passe o id pela url e recupere esse valor. Só tome cuidado para validar esse valor antes de usar.

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo esquece, é uma péssima ideia, só em última alternativa